# Order of convergence of linear fixed point iteration

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1/2 \\ -1/2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Define $(x_n)$ recursively by
$$
x_{n+1}=A x_n
$$
for some starting vector $x_0\neq 0\in\mathbb R^2$. Let $\vert\cdot\vert$ be the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^2$. I want to show that this iteration converges linearly, which means that
$$
\lim_n \frac{\vert x_{n+1}\vert}{\vert x_n\vert}\neq 0.
$$

*Some observations*:

Convergence is clear, since $1/2$ is the only eigenvalue. So let's move on to the showing that the limit exists and is non-zero. Numerically, it seems that the limit is equal to $1/2$, which is the spectral radius of $A$. If $x_0$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then it's clear from $x_{n+1}=Ax_n=1/2 x_n$ that the above quotient has limit $1/2$. However, how can I argue for $x_0$ which is not an eigenvector?

Maybe we can use that
$$
\vert x_{n+1}\vert\leq \vert A\vert \vert x_n\vert,
$$
where $\vert A\vert$ is the $2$-norm of $A$. Or maybe the Jordan-Canonical form is useful?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B1%2C+1%2F2%7D%2C%7B-1%2F2%2C0%7D%7D%5En

Comment: @Surb Nice! Then I can write down $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ explicitly, in which case it's clear that the limit goes to $1/2$. Thanks!